# Selenium auto-closes window after opening Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium opens a blank window before even calling this

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
username = 'something'
password = 'somethingelse'
instagram = 'https://www.instagram.com'
browser.get(instagram)
time.sleep(1.5)
username_field = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
username_field.send_keys(username)
password_field = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
password_field.send_keys(password)
time.sleep(1)
login = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']")
login.click()
print('I opened instagram')
```

then immediately after it closes. Any help?

Comment: It doesn't closes in my case. Check it again.

Answer (score 0):

In the `webdriver.Chrome()` try passing the chromedriver path like this.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"path/to/your/chromedriver.exe")
```

Hope that it might help.

Comment: It seems to close right before clicking the login button.